# uninitialized constant Authlogic::TestCase::ControllerAdapters (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, authlogic

I keep getting this error every time I try running my test just by ranning "rake":

> /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/authlogic-2.1.6/lib/authlogic/test_case/rails_request_adapter.rb:5:
>   uninitialized constant Authlogic::TestCase::ControllerAdapters
>   (NameError)

I have in the top of test_helper.rb these lines:

> require "authlogic/test_case" 
>   include Authlogic::TestCase

as suggested [here](http://rubydoc.info/github/binarylogic/authlogic/master/Authlogic/TestCase).

I use Rails 3.0.6 and I have the gem authlogic in the Gemfile as expected:

> gem "authlogic"

What am I missing? Why I cannot run the tests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so I finally solve the problem. The thing is that your test_helper.rb needs to have the require "authlogic/test_case" as said before. However, for some reason I don't fully understand, I also need to have a require "authlogic" before that one.

The I faced another problem because I had a fixture for user_sessions that was automatically generated. The solution was just deleting the fixture since authlogic doesnt create a table in the db for sessions. read more about this problem [here](http://buckybits.blogspot.com/2011/09/example-app-test-failures-from.html)